# imap-login director is not restarted after each auth request

Tags: dovecot, imap

imap-login by default in dovecot mail server is restarted after every login request keeping security in mind to avoid leak of critical data. But in a director config, the imap-login director process is not restarted on each auth request. Can somebody explain why this design decision is taken?

Answer (score 0):

`imap-login` deal with sensible data like user's login/pass that potentially can be extracted from the hacked process. `Director` have no sensible data inside so there is no reasons to hack/strength it.

When each user have its own `imap-login` process there is physical limit for simultaneous connections number (by RAM). Single shared process have no such limit.

Comment: Imap-login director process will get the user auth details right to lookup passdb. Am I missing something here?

Comment: `director` maintain the mapping between user and imap-server user attached to. That is used for clustering to ensure user will be directed to the same host each time. And then `imap-login` process perform authentication.

Comment: Director also has imap-login process which uses director socket for passdb lookup. This process is not renewed after successful logins